# Symfony upgrade to 3.3 service argument error

Tags: php, symfony

After upgrading to Symfony 3.3. I get this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException:
>   Invalid key "roles" found in arguments of method "setRoles()" for
>   service "authbundle.auth.repository.role": only integer or $named
>   arguments are allowed. in
>   /app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ResolveNamedArgumentsPass.php:47

This is my service definition:

```
authbundle.auth.repository.role:
  class: AuthBundle\Auth\Repository\RoleRepository
```

And here I am injecting a custom config into that service in the `AuthExtension` class:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(dirname(__DIR__).'/Resources/config'));
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
    $loader->load('services.yml');

    $roleRepositoryDef = $container->getDefinition('authbundle.auth.repository.role');
    $roleRepositoryDef->addMethodCall('setRoles', ['roles' => $config['roles']]);
}
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my method call was incorrect, I had to change it from

`$roleRepositoryDef->addMethodCall('setRoles', ['roles' => $config['roles']]);`

`$roleRepositoryDef->addMethodCall('setRoles', [$config['roles']]);`

So that the argument is not named

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did your original code work?  In other words, did upgrading to 3.3 actually break your code?

Comment: Yes I had that there for a month or two, working ok, tests making sure it worked etc, definitely stopped working after 3.1 -> 3.3 update

Comment: The [UPGRADE-3.3](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.3.md) document states that *[BC BREAK] non-numeric keys in methods and constructors arguments have never been supported and are now forbidden. Please remove them if you happen to have one.*.