# Symfony add doctrine to services.yml and custom extensions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

What I want achieve is call doctrine ini `TwigExtension`, I get some code from google and stackoverflow, like this :

service.yml

```
twig.extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        arguments:
            doctrine : '@doctrine'
        tags:
          -  { name: twig.extension }
```

AppBundle\Twig\AppEtension.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

}
```

I've followed all instruction from my source, but i still got error and cant call doctrine or do something with entitymanager here.

this is my error :

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                                                                       
  Invalid key "doctrine" found in arguments of method "__construct()" for service "twig.extension": only integer or $named arguments are allowed.
```

how to solve this?

Comment: check this link -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331420/symfony-upgrade-to-3-3-service-argument-error

Comment: Try with @doctrine.orm.entity_manager

Comment: @Jory's answer below is the correct solution.  The problem is that you are using an older version of Symfony but trying to follow the latest documentation.  Select the correct Symfony version in the service container doc page upper right corner and see the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `service.yml`, instead of `doctrine : '@doctrine'` you should have `$doctrine : '@doctrine'`.

The error you get makes an attempt at telling you this by saying `only integer or $named arguments are allowed` - note the **$**named part.